# Can't add line on the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new in R and I had to create a simple linear regression.

I get only dots but I can't add line to this dots explaining it's rising can someone help me to solve this problem?

[[image]]

Answer (score 6):

1. You can't use `abline` with `ggplot`. Use `geom_smooth` with `method = "lm"` instead.
2. You are missing a closing parenthesis `)`, as is evident by having the `+` symbol in the console, which means R is waiting for further input. In the script editor, while your cursor is on the last parenthesis, it is highlighting the parenthesis that it's closing.
3. It's generally not recommended to use `attach`.
4. You might want to read an introduction to `ggplot` and work through some examples.

To get to the plot you wanted, I would write:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = log(carat), y = log(price), col = color)) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = 'lm')
```

Comment: "generally not recommended to use attach"++ - **especially** with commands like `ggplot` that have a data argument!